# Prove little o with just the definition

Tags: algorithm-analysis, landau-notation, mathematical-foundations

I have been searching for a while now but couldn't find anything about this exact pair of functions with the little $\mathcal{o}$ notation.

Given the functions $f(n) = 2^{n}$ and $g(n) = n!$ I am supposed to prove, or disprove, the following statement: $f(n) \in \mathcal{o}(g(n))$.

I am fairly sure that it's true but now I need an idea of how to show this. We have just started out with this whole concept and this is the second exercise, the first one being a relatively easy big $\mathcal{O}$ task. But this exercise is just beyond me right now. The only definition I am allowed to use (meaning: NO LIMITS) is $\mathcal{o}(g(n)) = \{f(n)|\forall C > 0 \exists n_{0} \forall n\geq n_{0}:f(n) < C * g(n)\}$. This means other than with big $\mathcal{O}$, where it suffices to show that there's at least one pair $C$ and a $n_{0}$ so that $f(n) \leq C * g(n)$  $\forall n \geq n_{0}$, I now have to prove that for **every** $C > 0$, there is such a $n_{0}$ so that the condition stated in the set is true.

I first have been thinking about the functions, and I would have an answer for $\mathcal{O}$, because you can prove with induction that $2^{n} < n!, \forall n\geq 4$. Meaning my C would be 1 here. However, I have no idea how to prove it for every C and would be grateful for any guidance!
(It would already help to know how to start. Probably like, let $C$ be greater 0, and then I have to show that for any Value of this $C$, there is... because...
My biggest struggle is to find meaningful estimations to get a chain of inequalities.)

Comment: Try using Sterling’s approximation.

Comment: $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\lt1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4$ and  $\underbrace{2\cdot2\cdots2}_{n-5\  2\text{'s}}\lt5\cdot6\cdots n-1.$ So for $n\ge5$, $\underbrace{2\cdot2\cdots2}_{n \ 2\text{'s}}\lt1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdots(n-1)\cdot 2= n!/(n/2)$

Answer (score 3):

Pick $n_0 = \max\{ -\log c, 10 \}$. Then, for all $n \ge n_0 \ge 10$: 
$$
2^n = \frac{4^n}{2^n} \le \frac{4^n}{2^{n_0}} \le \frac{4^n}{1/c} =
c \cdot (4^{n-10} \cdot 4^{10}) <
c \cdot (4^{n-10} \cdot 10!) \le cn!
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove $f(n) = o(g(n))$ is to prove that:

$\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}
    &= 0
\end{align*}$

In this case, you know that:

$\begin{align*}
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}
     &= 0
\end{align*}$

since the series for $e^x$ converges for all $x$, so it converges for $x = 2$, and the terms of a convergent series have limit 0.

Or, if you take $n \ge 2$, you see that:

$\begin{align*}
   \frac{2^n}{n!}
     &= \frac{2}{1} \cdot \frac{2}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3}
          \dotsm \frac{2}{n}
\end{align*}$

Each successive factor after the second is smaller than 1, so the infinite product diverges to 0. That is, you can write for $n \ge 2$:

$\begin{align*}
   0 
     &\le \frac{2^n}{n!}
      \le \frac{2}{1} \cdot \frac{2}{2}
              \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^{n - 2}
\end{align*}$

As $n \to \infty$, the right hand side tends to 0.

Comment: The OP wanted a proof with quantifiers, probably as exercise

Answer (score 1):

$2^n$ is the product of n numbers which are all equal to 2.

n! is the product of n numbers from 1 to n.

Once n ≥ 3, if you increase n by 1, $2^n$ is doubled, while n! is multiplied by 4 or more. So basic maths shows that for n ≥ 3, $n! ≥ 6/64 \cdot 4^n$.

Given any C > 0 from the definition, you calculate how large n would have to be to make $2^n < 6/64 \cdot 4^n$.